# How can I finish my Ph.D within 9 months (when my funding runs out) when I have few results until now?

Tags: phd, advisor, graduation

Currently, I'm doing my Ph.D. in Biochemistry in Germany. I'm now in the 4th year. My fund will finish within 9 months.

My topic was changed after two years. Actually I was a lazy student with many responsibilities. I have very few results, which do not satisfy my supervisor. During my study, I faced many problems which embarrassed me in learning my area of research.

Now I have opened my eyes, but I'm afraid that I will lose everything and I will not get the degree. I'm asking about tips and advice? Is it possible to convince my supervisor within this short time and finish my Ph.D. within these 9 months?

Comment: Down voted. I think this falls into the category of *shopping questions*.

Comment: Other than a sense of urgency, what do you anticipate will change over the next nine months relative to the previous three years?

Comment: This will depend *heavily* on how many and what kind of results you already have. Random strangers on the internet can't answer this question for you. You need to talk to your advisor *as soon as possible* and work out a possible plan of action to salvage what can be salvaged. You may be able to get some money as a TA/RA ("wissenschaftliche Hilfskraft") after your grant runs out, but your supervisor will want to see you put your nose to the grindstone.

Comment: My results not that much, I know nobody can answer, what I need are tips and kind of hope and motivation

Comment: @Martin: Check out this post then: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/how-should-i-deal-with-discouragement-as-a-graduate-student

Comment: It is possible to work part time and continue with research and writing up results.

Comment: I actually think this should be opened and answered...  @StephanKolassa's comment forms a complete and correct answer. Especially given that funding extension is possible this really stands out as a healthy question.

Comment: @djechlin: Stephan Kolassa’s answer essentially says the same thing as the close reason. Avoiding such answers is one of the reasons why this close reason exists.