# How to stay calm on days of no progress?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, emotional-responses, productivity

I'm a math PhD student working in Pure Mathematics. I guess, everybody is familiar with those days when you make very little progress or no progress at all. As the title suggests, I would like to know how do you stay calm and relaxed on those days?

Every time I have such days, it makes me very anxious and I feel like I wasted my time. It makes me feel very unproductive.

Comment: Have you seen these question? [1. How should I deal with becoming discouraged as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219/17254), [2. Why is my mood dictated so much by how well my research is going?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71323/17254)

Comment: "Every time I have such days, it makes me very anxious and I feel like I wasted my time". You didn't: http://vigeland.caltech.edu/ist4/lectures/Poincare%20Reflections.pdf