# What motivates you to do research?

Tags: research-undergraduate, motivation, remote-work

I am a research undergraduate student who is in full time research internship in university. I realized that research needs A LOT of patience to obtain validated results A LOT of exploration. A LOT of roads and initial ideas that lead to no results or can't be implemented. I don't feel the dopamine rush that i feel when working on short term projects. So how do you stay motivated ? what's your secret ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with discouragement as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/how-should-i-deal-with-discouragement-as-a-graduate-student)

Comment: There is a saying in math: "You don't choose mathematics. Mathematics chooses you." Some of us are just driven by ideas. You either power through frustrations or learn to sidestep them.

Comment: A properly structured undergraduate research project should __not__ involve many _"roads and initial ideas that lead to no results or can't be implemented."_  If it does, there is something wrong, and shouldn't be asked to work on it in the first place.  Your project should be then broken down into a chain of smaller milestones which are ambitious yet feasible.

Comment: I have found research to be incredibly more stimulating for me than almost anything else. I absolutely HATE when I come up against problems on what feels like literally a daily basis, but after I work through those problems, it's a very wonderful feeling. So I have an immense love-hate relationship with research. Being able to do research is incredibly liberating for me, even when I hate doing it.

Comment: You feel quite good when completing a short term project. Imagine how good the feeling is when you finally fix all the problems and find the right way to proceed and complete a long term project.